# How to call Sabre EnhancedSeatMapRQ soap web service from .NET?

Tags: .net, soap, sabre

I am able to invoke EnhancedSeatMapRQ in TSTS environment from SoapUI. When I use Visual Studio 2015 generated Soap proxies to make the same call, I am getting null deserialized Items section. I also get "Completed" (success) in ApplicationResults section. I can see with Fiddler that the call was actually successful and that problem is due to .Net deserialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EnhancedSeatMapRQ v3.0 does not seem to deserialize correctly the response.

There's a WSDL created for v2.0 specifically for .NET, until the other WSDL is corrected you can use that one, here's the link:
http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/providerdoc/Merchandising/EnhancedSeatMapService_2_0_dotNET.zip

Comment: Also EnhancedSeatMapRQ v4.0 does not deserialize correctly.

Comment: v5.0 has been released, it was said to be .NET compatible, you might want to try it out